# About the limit points in a particular topology.

Tags: general-topology

I am reading an article in which the following example is presented:

''Let $A$ be the set of all reals which are not integers. let $\{x\}$ be closed for all $x\in A$, in addition let the sets $\left[ n-\frac{1}{2},n+\frac{1}{2} \right]\setminus \{n\}$ be closed for all integers $n$. Finally let all finite unions of sets of these types be closed.'' (Also considered the empty set and $\mathbb{R}$)

The article mentions that for each $x \in X$, the set of limit points for $\{x\}$ is closed.

My attempt:

I tried to calculate the set of limit points for each set $\{x\}$, but I'm not sure I'm right. (I will denote the set of limit points of ${x}$ by $\{x\}'$).
\begin{equation*}
\{x\}'=
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{R}-\{x\} & \quad\quad\quad\text{if }x\in\mathbb{Z} \\
\emptyset & \quad\quad\quad\text{if }x\notin \mathbb{Z}
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation*}
For $x \notin \mathbb{Z}$ it is easy because given $y\neq x$ we ​​consider $U=(-\infty,x)\cup(x,\infty)$.
My reasoning for $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ was that everything open contains $x$, so for every $y\neq x$, every neighborhood of $y$ contains $x$.

So, my problem is that the set $\{x\}'$ is not closed for $x\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is $X$? Is it $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @GReyes Yes, $X=\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Link to the article.

Comment: @Jakobian That is the article: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82702431.pdf   (page 10 in the PDF)
The definition of $T_D-$space is Definition 3.1, on page 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you didn't mention is that $[n-\frac{1}{2}, n+\frac{1}{2}]$ is closed in $X$, they mention that in the article you linked to in the comments, and I will assume so.

Note that $\{x\}'$ is the set of those points $y\in X$ such that for every neighbourhood $U$ of $y$, $x\in U\setminus \{y\}$. If $y\neq x$ this is the same as saying that $y\in \overline{\{x\}}$, that is $\{x\}' = \overline{\{x\}}\setminus\{x\}$.

If $x\notin \mathbb{Z}$, then $\{x\}' = \emptyset$ since $\overline{\{x\}} = \{x\}$ by definition of topology on $X$.

If $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $\overline{\{x\}} = [x-\frac{1}{2}, x+\frac{1}{2}]$ so that $\{x\}' = [x-\frac{1}{2}, x+\frac{1}{2}]\setminus \{x\}$ is closed.

Comment: Ohhh thank you. Due to a translation error I was not considering those sets as closed. Thank you again.